# Excel - RIGHT formula not working as expected

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formula

[image: RIGHT formula]

I am trying to get the last 4 characters (the year in this case) from one column to be displayed in a new column. As far as I am aware, the formula I am doing is correct but the column isn't displaying the correct values (should be 2016, 2015 etc)

Comment: Have you tried =--RIGHT(H2,4) ?

Comment: Dates are numbers, you are getting the rightmost 4 digits in those numbers. If you want the year of the date, better to use `=YEAR(H2)`

Comment: Have you tried checking by pressing CTRL ~ does those dates changes to a number and left aligned(dates are actually stored as number in excel and are always right aligned), then you can use `YEAR` function, but if it doesnt changes then you may have to use the `RIGHT` function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first, use right() for each cell:

```
=right(H2,4)
```

Then get excel to recognize the result as a number not text (text is left and numbers right formatted in the cell):

```
=right(H2,4)*1 or =value(right(H2,4))
```

But, as others have pointed out, dates are represented in Excel with a serial number - try changing the formatting and you will see.

Comment: Ah thank you, yes this is it. so after I converted the dates from 'date' format to 'text' then the formula was acting accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Try `=YEAR(H2)` instead? `RIGHT` formula does not work ideally for dates.

Comment: Thank you, this answer also solves my problem